# How can I improve my function that gets parents from a file or folder path?

Tags: performance, postgresql, plpgsql

Here's my function to get parents from a file or folder path:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION storage.__object_get_parents(p_object_path varchar, p_tolowercase boolean)
RETURNS varchar[] AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _arr varchar[];
    _parents varchar[];
    _parent varchar;
    _parent_prev varchar;
    _object_path varchar;
    _cnt int := 0;
    _val varchar;
BEGIN
    if p_tolowercase then
        _object_path := lower(substr(p_object_path, 1, length(p_object_path)-1));
    else
        _object_path := substr(p_object_path, 1, length(p_object_path)-1);
    end if;
    _arr := string_to_array(_object_path, '/', '');
    _parent_prev := '';
    for i in 1 .. array_upper(_arr, 1)-1 loop
        _val := _arr[i];
        if _val IS NOT NULL then
            _parent := _parent_prev || _val || '/';
            _parents := array_append(_parents, _parent);
            _cnt := _cnt + 1;
        else
            -- ignore double slashes: replace previsouly added element
            _parent := _parent_prev || '/';
            _parents[_cnt] := _parent;
        end if;
        _parent_prev := _parent;
    end loop;

    RETURN coalesce(_parents,'{}'::varchar[]);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'function __object_get_parents() is failed! ErrCode (%) (%)', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE;
```

When I run this against a path with many components, it's really slow:

```
select array_length(storage.__object_get_parents('d2140247-ef9d-4d51-ac28-ba008c378720/H%3A/files/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/doc/',false),1);
 array_length 
--------------
         2145
(1 row)

Time: 13885.555 ms
```

How can I increase its speed?

Comment: Your code could really use some comments.

Comment: Suggestion: 1) Move `array_upper(_arr, 1)-1` out of the loop. 2) Instead of `array_append` use `_parents[cnt] := _parent`.

Comment: BTW, PostgreSQL 9.5.2 - 125 msec.

Comment: Hint: Use `raise notice '%', clock_timestamp();` to find out which part(s) of your function is slow.

Comment: Thanks @JimmyB , Point 2 can be a minor improvement. Point 1 can't, as it only executes 1 time.

Comment: Thanks @Abelisto as well.

Comment: @K.G. You're right. ["The two expressions giving the lower and upper bound of the range are evaluated once when entering the loop."](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-INTEGER-FOR)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are generating a hideous amount of data. If you have 2145 parents in a string that is about 8kB in length, then you produce an array of 2145 elements of a length starting with something small and ending in nearly 8kB, for an average of 4kB. At 2145 parents you therefore generate about 8MB of data. Do you really need all of that? Do you really ever need all of those parents from one function call?

Maybe you should tell us *what you really want* and then we can see what a suitable function would be.

That said, using `psql` against a local 9.5 server I clock 23.8 ms of planning time and a whopping 0.011 ms of running time. Your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: You're right that the issue lies on planning time. My purpose is to get all parents. It cannot be changed. Thanks, you help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`plpgsql` functions usually not offers the fastest solution, plain SQL solutions will always perform better, so you should search for SQL solutions first (and you could create an `sql` function form it, if you are sure you want to wrap your logic inside a function).

Recursive CTE is the typical solution to your problem:

```
with recursive path(path) as (
  values ('d2140247-ef9d-4d51-ac28-ba008c378720//H%3A/files/doc/doc/doc/doc/.../doc/doc/')
),
rparents(rpath) as (
    select reverse(trim(trailing '/' from path))
    from   path
  union all
    select trim(leading '/' from substring(rpath from p))
    from   rparents, position('/' in rpath) p
    where  p > 0
)
select reverse(rpath)
from   rparents
```

But unfortunately, searching in a string from the end of it is not possible, so multiple calling of the `reverse()` function is needed to achieve that kind of functionality.

Another solution would be to use window functions:

```
with path(path) as (
  values ('d2140247-ef9d-4d51-ac28-ba008c378720//H%3A/files/doc/doc/doc/doc/.../doc/doc/')
)
select string_agg(unnest, '/') over (order by ordinality)
from   path, unnest(string_to_array(path, '/')) with ordinality
where  unnest != ''
```

**Note**: `with ordinality` is a 9.4+ feature, but you can simulate it with a sub-select and `row_number()`.

Also, if you really want to get an array of parent paths (as opposed to a result-set of them), you can use `array_agg()` (and possibly a sub-select).

Both of these performs better than a `plpgsql` function, but if you use such long paths as in your question, they will be still slow, because of IO.

**Edit**: a version, which treats slash characters as part of the folder name, when followed by another slash:

```
with path(path) as (
  values ('d2140247-ef9d-4d51-ac28-ba008c378720//H%3A/files/doc///doc/doc/doc/.../doc/doc/')
)
select string_agg(regexp_split_to_table, '/') over (order by ordinality)
from   path, regexp_split_to_table(path, '/(?!/)') with ordinality
where  regexp_split_to_table != ''
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I thought about using plain SQL before. But I can't think of method to ignore double slashes. For example, with path "folder1/folder2///folder3/file1", "folder2//" is regarded as a folder name, so expected result are "folder1/",  "folder1/folder2//" and "folder1/folder2//folder3/".

Comment: @K.G. The window function solution strips double slashes, and the recursive CTE ignores them, but returns them in the results. Give them a try.